# Android x86 port - Change SSID/BSSID of default wifi

Tags: android, android-x86

I am currently using the latest build of the Android x86 port (https://www.android-x86.org/), and struggling to find a way to change the SSID and BSSID of the default wifi.  When I connect to the Wifi, it uses the SSID "VirtWifi".  Is this possible to change?

The reason for wanting to change this is primarily for testing.  I have an app where I need to test against different Wifi access points and so being able to change the wifi would be very helpful.

I am using Android x86 version 9.0.2.